# What gem/script can I use to create a email reminder app with Rails & jquery?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery

I want to create a basic web app where a user can log in and type infortmaion and then set the date and time for a email reminder.

What gem/script can I use to create a email reminder app with Rails & jquery?

Thanks and hope I'm not too vague.

Erin

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [delayed jobs](https://github.com/tobi/delayed_job) gem to schedule a job that will send the email at the appropriate time. And for sending the email itself, you can use [ActionMailer](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionMailer/Base.html).

Comment: Oops, you beat me by a few minutes!

Comment: Thanks - will see how it goes!

Answer (score 0):

There are few parts to be consider

E-Mail layout and templates

You should give a try on

liquid (http://www.liquidmarkup.org/) (ruby markup language)

redcloth (http://redcloth.org/) on textile markup

and when it comes to sending mail (as @Chentir mentioned)

delayed jobs

ActionMailer

and you shouldn't miss out followings as well

http://leadthinking.com/233-sending-or-receiving-emails-with-rails

http://railscasts.com/episodes/61-sending-email

HTH

cheers

sameera